# calculate the infinite integral $ \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{x}\cos(x)dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

$ \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{x}\cos(x)dx $

I'm trying to solve the integral,

I got: $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{x}\cos(x)dx=\lim_{b\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}e^{x}(\sin(x)+\cos(x))\right)\mid_{0}^{b}$

but I don't know how to solve this limit, I got:
$$
\lim_{b\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}e^{x}(\sin(x)+\cos(x))\right)\mid_{0}^{b}=\lim_{b\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}e^{b}(\sin(b)+\cos(b))-\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
but the value of $\sin(b)+\cos(b)$ can be negative/positive...

thanks, and sorry if I have English mistakes...

Comment: The limit does not exist since the $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ functions are just going back and forth 1 and -1, multiplying it to $e^x$ will make the limit does not exist. The integral is what you call a 'divergent integral'

Comment: Yaa, but it's indefinite integral can be found.

Comment: The sequence/function in the last line "converges" neither to $\infty$ nor $-\infty$, nor does it converge to a real number as $b\to\infty$.

Comment: @RAHUL Yes, and OP already found the indefinite integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are concerned, whether
$$ \lim _{b\to\infty} e^{b}(\sin b + \cos b)$$ exists.
On the one hand, along the sequence $b_n = \frac{3\pi}{4} + 2n\pi$, the limit is zero. On the other hand, for $b_n = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi$ the limit is $\infty$. The initial limit does not exist as $b\to\infty$. Consequently, the  improper integral diverges.